# Why is Wrapper Integer to Float conversion not possible in java

Tags: java, type-conversion, wrapper

Why the typecasting of Wrapper Float does not works in java for Wrapper Integer type.

```
public class Conversion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = 234;

        Float b = (Float)i;

        System.out.println(b);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An `Integer` is not a `Float`.  With objects, the cast would work if `Integer` subclassed `Float`, but it does not.

Java will not auto-unbox an `Integer` into an `int`, cast to a `float`, then auto-box to a `Float` when the only code to trigger this desired behavior is a `(Float)` cast.

Interestingly, this seems to work:

```
Float b = (float)i;
```

Java will auto-unbox `i` into an `int`, then there is the explicit cast to `float` (a [widening primitive conversion, JLS 5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)), then assignment conversion auto-boxes it to a `Float`.

Comment: This produces a NullPointerException if i is null. The solution is not safe.

Comment: @RédaHousniAlaoui While null-checking in general is a good idea, in this question `i` is not `null`.

Comment: I get your point but I think the code provided by the OP is only an experiment. I don't think he knows the value of i in production context. Anyway, at least it will be a warning for those who think your solution applies everywhere :)

Answer (score 2):

You are asking it to do too much.  You want it to unbox i, cast to float and then box it.  The compiler can't guess that unboxing i would help it.  If, however, you replace (Float) cast with (float) cast it will guess that i needs to be unboxed to be cast to float and will then happily autobox it to Float.

Answer (score 1):

Wrappers are there to *"objectify"* the related primitive types. This sort of casting is done on the *"object-level"* to put it in a way, and not the actual value of the wrapped primitive type.

Since there's no relation between `Float` and `Integer` per se (they're related to `Number` but they're just siblings) a cast can't be done directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Conversion {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i = 234;

    Float b = i.floatValue();

    System.out.println(b);

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your class to work like you want:

```
public class Conversion {

     public Float intToFloat(Integer i) {
          return (Float) i.floatValue();
     }

}
```

Comment: This produces a NullPointerException if i is null. The solution is not safe.